# bytes4(keccak256("function(uint256)")) vs. (abi.encodeWithSignature("buyItem(uint256)")

Tags: solidity, abi, keccak

What is the (a) technical difference between and (b) practical difference between these, i.e., when do you use one or the other:

```
bool result = address(contract).call.value(10)(bytes4(keccak256("buyItem(uint256)", _sku)));

bool result = address(contract).call.value(10)(abi.encodeWithSignature("buyItem(uint256)", _sku));
```

The code refers to an exercise where we buy an inventory item, identified by `_sku` (a `uint`) for an amount `value` aka `msg.value`  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

as per solidity documentation [here](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/050-breaking-changes.html?highlight=keccak)

`keccak256()` now accept only a single bytes argument. Moreover, the argument is not padded. This was changed to make more explicit and clear how the arguments are concatenated.

Change every `keccak256(a, b, c)` to `keccak256(abi.encodePacked(a, b, c))`.

Even though it is not a breaking change, it is suggested that developers change `x.call(bytes4(keccak256("f(uint256)"), a, b)` to `x.call(abi.encodeWithSignature("f(uint256)", a, b))`.

Comment: For anyone else creating their own Modules with Gnosis' Zodiac framework, this answer will save you a lot of headache, thanks!!!